# Error in Visio while saving Process Definition

Tags: workflow

I am creating one process definition in visio 2010 that is connected to Tridion CMS but I am not able to save that process Definition.

I am getting following error:

```
Empty connnection encountered
  getconnectedshape()
  getprocessdefinitionXML()
```

[image]

Comment: Can you share the screen shot of the error. In addition, can you check the Logs and look for the additional error.

Also, are you doing this on your local machine or on the CMS server itself?

Comment: Thanks Pankaj But I am doing this in Tridion CMS only just check the attached error iamge.

Comment: See comments from Puntero, that is one of the possible reason.
In addition check the Windows Event Logs on CMS server for SDL Tridion Content Manager and see if there is any error with more description that helps you identify the issue.

Answer (score 4):

Check your connection between activities on the diagram

That error indicates that you have 2 activities not properly connected. If you click on an activity and it doesn't show red dots on the connections, it means its not properly connected.

**Update:** A space at the end of the definition name would generate the same error